# fadein only if I'm scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this snippet to make an element fade out if `scrolltop` is `>` 750 and fade in when it's `<` 750. It works fine but I'd like it to remain not visible when scrolling back up (after it faded out) until user reaches the top of the page.

So, this is what's currently happening:
element is visible by default, user scrolls 750 and it fades out. User reaches end of the page, scrolls back up and when reaches 750 the element fades back in.

```
var $window = $(window);
var $freccia = $('#freccia1');

function showHideFreccia() {
   var availableScroll = $(document).height() - $window.height(),
       scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

   if( scrollTop < 750 || scrollTop  == availableScroll) {
        $freccia.fadeIn("slow", function() {
        });
   } else {
        $freccia.fadeOut("slow", function() {
        });
   }
}

showHideFreccia();
$window.scroll(showHideFreccia);
```

What should be changed is:
element is visible by default, user scrolls 750 and it fades out. User reaches end of the page, scrolls back up **and when reaches top of the page** the element fades back in.

I tried with this but it's not working (doesn't fade in/out anymore):

```
var $window = $(window);
var $freccia = $('#freccia1');

function showHideFreccia() {
   var availableScroll = $(document).height() - $window.height(),
       scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

   if ( scrollTop > 750 || scrollTop  == availableScroll) {
        $freccia.fadeout("slow", function() {
        });
   }
   if ( scrollTop < 1 || scrollTop  == availableScroll) {
        $freccia.fadein("slow", function() {
        });
   }
}

showHideFreccia();
$window.scroll(showHideFreccia);
```

Comment: is it your exact code? Because you're missing uppercase on fadein and out. Should be fadeIn and fadeOut

Comment: Yep it's my actual code... I'm not getting warnings or errors..

Comment: Oh ok, understood. I'm trying now to change it

Comment: Yep!! Was that simple.. sorry..! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second code snippet works fine, you've just used **fadein** and **fadeout** instead of **fadeIn** and **fadeOut**, a common mistake!

This code is working fine for me: 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqyf0rtn/)

```
var $window = $(window);
var $freccia = $('#freccia1');

function showHideFreccia() {
   var availableScroll = $(document).height() - $window.height(),
       scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

   if ( scrollTop > 750 || scrollTop  == availableScroll) {
        $freccia.fadeOut("slow", function() {
        });
   }
   if ( scrollTop < 1 || scrollTop  == availableScroll) {
        $freccia.fadeIn("slow", function() {
        });
   }
}

showHideFreccia();
$window.scroll(showHideFreccia);
```

**EDIT:**

Unsure if this is what you want to happen or not, but this current code will show the element again when you reach the end of the page. You can fix this just by removing the `|| scrollTop  == availableScroll` from your second if statement (if it's not needed at all, it can be removed from the first also).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script, to apply in your scroll top:

```
var detectScroll = function (_event) {
    var event = window.event || _event; // old IE support
    var direction = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (event.wheelDelta || -event.detail)));
    return direction;
   };

function showHideFreccia(e) {
    var dir = detectScroll(e);
    //...
    if ( dir == 1 || scrollTop  == availableScroll) {
        // your action
    }
}
// and into your scroll event
$window.scroll(function(e) {
    showHideFreccia(e);
});
```

[**Source**](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/)

If it will return `1` it means, that you scroll up then execute your `fadein` action. `-1` me means scroll to bottom

Comment: Where should I put this?